Is the balance of the channel safe if I set unilateraltimeout to 0 and go offline when mutually closing the channel?
I run a core lighning node with a couple of private, single-founded channels.
Because of my circumstances my node is usually online for a couple of hours every three days or so.
I want to mutually close one of my lightning channels, and
am thinking of running:
lightning-cli -k "id=${scid}" unilateraltimeout=10800 feerange=[2000, normal]

where scid is the short_channel_id of the channel to be closed. I
set unilateraltimeout to 10800 seconds, i.e. 3 hours.
I consider also setting the parameter to 0 or skipping it (it then defaults to 48 hours)
Is it safe to set unilateraltimeout to 0 and go offline when mutually closing the channel?
